# MySQL console. Linux. Result field length is twice longer than the longest its ciryllic string

Tags: mysql

I found that result table field is much longer than its the longest string value if it is Cyrillic (and probably other non-latin). I need to get pretty compact result.

```
mysql> select * from tmp7 limit 1;
+-------+
| dir   |
+-------+
| latin |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tmp7 limit 2;
+------------------+
| dir              |
+------------------+
| latin            |
| Кирилица         |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tmp7;
+----------------------------------+
| dir                              |
+----------------------------------+
| latin                            |
| Кирилица                         |
| КирилицаКирилица                 |
+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tmp7;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tmp7  | CREATE TABLE `tmp7` (
  `dir` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this a bug of MySQL? Is there any workaround?

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
>   readline 6.2

Comment: `CHAR` has fixed length, whereas `VARCHAR` variable, it's as compact as it gets, I think this is the number of characters, if you use a `BYTE` field, it's the number of bytes instead

Comment: I think mysql figures out the width of the box based on the largest number of bytes in the result, and doesn't take into account that some of these are multi-byte characters.

Comment: You are right Barmar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might be because utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per character. So while the string in the third result looks to be 16 characers (КирилицаКирилица), it requires 32 characters to store so the box is 32 characters wide. I would assume in this instance the characters in the string themselves are using 2 bytes each. It looks like the mysql client is checking the max field length is 32 characters (even though this results in 16 characters).

You can test this by trying to store the value:

```
ирилицаКирилицаирилицаКирилица
```

Which would require 64 characters to store, and would be truncated.

Comment: Yes, short answer is that field length in select result depends on number of bytes in a string containing max bytes. I checked that by inserting Chinese string with the same 16 chars and the field became even longer. When I saved both Cyrillic and Chinese strings in separate files in utf8 encoding first contained 33 bytes whereas second one 49. Thank you!